# Toastr Message not Showing in ajax crud

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, toastr

I try to show toastr message in my ajax crud but only the toastr modal is pop up and nothing is displayed in the modal. I add all the necessary cdn in the master layout and script tag also. Data stored successfully in the database and normal success message show, but I want to show the toastr message and I failed.

**I have added CSS and JS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.css" integrity="sha512-3pIirOrwegjM6erE5gPSwkUzO+3cTjpnV9lexlNZqvupR64iZBnOOTiiLPb9M36zpMScbmUNIcHUqKD47M719g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js" integrity="sha512-VEd+nq25CkR676O+pLBnDW09R7VQX9Mdiij052gVCp5yVH3jGtH70Ho/UUv4mJDsEdTvqRCFZg0NKGiojGnUCw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

**I have added master layout script code:**

```
    <script>
    @if (Session::has('success'))
        toastr.options = {
            "closeButton": true,
            "progressBar": true
        }
        toastr.success("{{ session('success') }}");
    @endif
    @if (Session::has('error'))
        toastr.options = {
            "closeButton": true,
            "progressBar": true
        }
        toastr.error("{{ session('error') }}");
    @endif
    @if (Session::has('info'))
        toastr.options = {
            "closeButton": true,
            "progressBar": true
        }
        toastr.info("{{ session('info') }}");
    @endif
    @if (Session::has('warning'))
        toastr.options = {
            "closeButton": true,
            "progressBar": true
        }
        toastr.warning("{{ session('warning') }}");
    @endif
</script>
```

**Controller Code**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'course' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 404,
            'errors' => $validator->messages(),
        ]);
    }
    else {
        $student = new Student;
        $student->name = $request->name;
        $student->email = $request->email;
        $student->phone = $request->phone;
        $student->course = $request->course;
        $student->save();
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 200,
            // 'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Successfully created',
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Blade Script Ajax Code**

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/students",
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    // console.log(response);
                    if(response.status === 404) {
                        $('#saveform_errList').html("");
                        $('#saveform_errList').addClass('alert alert-danger');
                        $.each(response.errors, function (key, err_values) { 
                            $('#saveform_errList').append('<list>' + err_values + '</list>');
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        Toastr.success(response.message);
                        // $('#saveform_errList').html("");
                        // $('#success_message').addClass('alert alert-success');
                        // $('#success_message').text(response.message);
                        $('#AddStudentModal').modal('hide');
                        $('#AddStudentModal').find('input').val("");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have another style link interrupting it, perhaps bootsrap, where the toastr style may have been set contrary to your own background color.
I experienced that once.